In SwiftUI is it possible to use both .onDrag and .gesture(DragGesture()) simultaneously?
I have an item view that has a .simultaneousGesture(DragGesture()) modifier on it to handle dragging the item around a Canvas and updating its x and y position. I also want to add an .onDrag modifier to handle dragging and dropping the item between different views. But these two are interfering with each other.
I've tried placing .onDrag both before and after the gesture, but neither position solved my problem.
If .onDrag is placed before the .simultaneousGesture, the .onDrag event triggers as expected, and so does the .simultaneousGesture, but only for the first few updates. If it's placed after, only the .simultaneousGesture is recognized.
Below is the code for the View and further below I'm attaching a screenshot of the console output after I drag the FileView.
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
    
struct FileView: View {
    @ObservedObject var form: Forms.File

    @State private var firstClick: Bool = false
    @State private var mousedown: Bool = false
    @State private var initialDragOffset = CGSize.zero
    @State private var hovering: Bool = false
    @ObservedObject private var windowSize = WindowSize.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: "doc.fill")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 17, height: 17)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .scaleEffect(x: 1, y: mousedown ? 0.8 : 1)
                .foregroundColor(form.isSelected ? Color.red : Color.black)
                .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
            Text(form.name)
        }
        .frame(height: 30)
        .onHover { hovering in
            self.hovering = hovering
        }
        .padding(.leading, 8)
        .padding(.trailing, 8)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                .stroke(form.isSelected ? Color.red : Color.clear, lineWidth: 1)
        )
        .position(
            x: windowSize.width * form.canvasPosition.x,
            y: windowSize.height * form.canvasPosition.y
        )
        .onDrag {
            print("DRAGGING")
            return NSItemProvider(object: form.path as NSString)
        }
        .simultaneousGesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0.10)
            .onChanged { gesture in
                if initialDragOffset == .zero {
                    let initialX = windowSize.width * form.canvasPosition.x
                    let initialY = windowSize.height * form.canvasPosition.y
                    initialDragOffset = CGSize(width: gesture.location.x - initialX,
                                               height: gesture.location.y - initialY)
                }

                let newX = (gesture.location.x - initialDragOffset.width) / windowSize.width
                let newY = (gesture.location.y - initialDragOffset.height) / windowSize.height
                form.updatedAt = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
                form.canvasPosition.x = newX
                form.canvasPosition.y = newY
                print(newX, newY)
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                initialDragOffset = .zero
            }
        )
        .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.01, pressing: { isPressing in
            if isPressing {
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.1)) {
                    mousedown = true
                }
            } else {
                if firstClick {
                    form.open()
                } else {
                    firstClick = true
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
                        firstClick = false
                    }
                }
                
                if(form.isSelected) {
                    mousedown = false
                } else {
                    withAnimation(Animation.interpolatingSpring(mass: 2.0, stiffness: 80, damping: 8, initialVelocity: 0).speed(6)) {
                        mousedown = false
                        form.isSelected.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
        }){}
    }
}

As you can see in the output, onChanged prints once before the .onDrag event triggers and once after, but never again as I continue dragging. Is there any of way of having these two modifiers work in harmony?
Console output
note: I tried but I don't know how to embed the image instead of just showing the link :(

You can't have the same gesture on the same view twice (How would it know which one you want to trigger?). You would need to add the first .onDrag onto the inner views (maybe wrap them again) and then your simultaneousGesture should call as well.
